# Handling the resuts of modal window in vue app

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to use modal from "Bootstrap + Vue" in my project.

Now this may be a basic question, but after searching for a while I didn't find any answer so I will go ahead and ask.

Consider the following modal

```
<b-modal ref="myModalRef"  @ok="handleOk">
    Are You Sure You Want To Delete?
</b-modal>
```

So, if I want to handle the `ok` button it is straight forward

```
export default {
  methods: {
   handleOk: function() {
      alert('alert form table - ok is pressed!!')
    }
  }
}
```

However, in my case I have the following scenario where I want to know what was pressed inside my `deleteRow` function which has a knowledge of `person` as opposed to handleOk which is `person` agnostic:

```
deleteRow: function(person){
   //show dialog 
   this.$refs.myModalRef.show()
   // it would be nice to know here what was pressed
    if (okpressed) 
       actuallyDetele(person)
}
```

in other words I am looking for functionality  like `confirm` but I would like to use  modals.

```
var r = confirm("Are You Sure You Want To Delete?");
if (r == true) {
    // continue 
} else {
   //do nothing 
}
```

Any suggestions how can I achieve that with modals.

Thanks.

Comment: Usually those prompts works with promises, try: `.open().then(yes => yes ? console.log('continue') : console.warn('canceled'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Bootstrap Vue` modals triggers `@ok` event when you press ok. You can use it like:

```
<b-modal id="deleteModal"
             ref="modal"
             title="Are you sure?"
             @ok="deleteYourUser"
             @shown="anotherFunct">
```

And always pre-select the user and preserve it in a data var to use inside delete function. You have no other way to pass to the modal the user that you will want to eliminate later if you confirm.

Comment: So, as there are no other suggestions - As i see it - the only way is to use auxiliary variable, store there the `person` (this will happen in  `deleteRow`) and then perform the rest of the operation (`actuallyDetele(person)`)  from  `handleOk` by referencing the auxiliary variable.  Thanks for your reply. I am going to up-vote and  accept that.